# Reduce a double in swift

Tags: swift, double

I am trying to reduce the amount of characters in a double. How Would I reduce this:

```
59.5220000
```

to

```
59.5
```

this in swift?

Comment: You should look into the [NumberFormatter class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter). It may look daunting because it uses another class `NSNumber`, but NSNumbers are easily initialized from Doubles

Comment: Are you simply trying to round the result to once decimal place in the user interface? Or do you really need the number rounded for other reasons?

Answer (score 2):

A double doesn't have characters. A string rendering of it does. Rather than using the standard `String()` initializer (which is really only for development use, it's terrible for end-users), use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use a formatted string?

```
let str = String(format: "%.2f", 59.5220000)
```

Comment: If this string is for display in the user interface, this `String(format:_:)` is not localized. `NumberFormatter` is much better solution for displaying results in the UI...